# How to select a portion of a table with plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, css-selectors

I use jQuery for this but I can't use it now (no reason for this). I need to select a portion of a table and then print it.

I use this code:

```
function Printon(this)
{
    newWin= window.open('','','toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=800, height=1000, left=10, top=25');
    newWin.document.write('<table>' + document.getElementsByName(this).innerHTML + '</table>');
    newWin.document.close();
    newWin.focus();
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
    return false;
}
```

When then calling the function with parameter of the `<tr>` names I just get a document with:

```
12-11-12

undefined
```

I am sure my HTML is correct but still here is my HTML:

```
<tr name="Print_1">
    <td>dhr Kees-jan ckc Von fleppenstein</td>
    <td>aquaduct straat 66<br>0606 OP ORK</td>
    <td>WDB-1352303696</td>
    <td>2822.00</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Print this" onclick="Printon('Print_1')"></td>
    <td> &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr name="Print_1">
    <td>-</td>
    <td> &nbsp;</td>
    <td> &nbsp;</td>
    <td>46.00</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Actiesalade herfst</td>
</tr>
<tr name="Print_1">
    <td>-</td>
    <td> &nbsp;</td>
    <td> &nbsp;</td>
    <td>46.00</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Actiesalade herfst</td>
</tr>
```

On inspiration of @Muthu Kumaran I use this:

```
function Printon(dit)
{
    var arr = new Array(); 
    arr = document.getElementsByName(dit); 
    var tabel = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
         tabel += document.getElementsByName(dit)[i].outerHTML;
    }

    newWin= window.open('','','toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=800, height=1000, left=10, top=25');
    newWin.document.write('<table border=\"2\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">' + tabel + '</table>');
    newWin.document.close();
    newWin.focus();
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
    return false;
}
```

Fixed it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `this` as a argument in the function. Give a proper variable like name. Also `document.getElementsByName` will return array of elements, so you have to get the value by using `document.getElementsByName(name)[0]`

Try this,

```
function Printon(name)
{
    newWin= window.open('','','toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=800, height=1000, left=10, top=25');
    newWin.document.write('<table>' + document.getElementsByName(name)[0].innerHTML + '</table>');
    newWin.document.close();
    newWin.focus();
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
    return false;
}
```

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/RxNKn/1/

Comment: Aha that makes sense. When calling on a named object I need to loop trough all of them because they are ordered like in an array. I thought using getElementsByName(name) would select all the elements but I was wrong. Making a loop now!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string 'Print_1' and in the function you are using this. 'this' will not contain 'Print_1'.

Better use a variable instead of this. Change your function to something like below.

```
function Printon(var tableName)
                {
                    newWin= window.open('','','toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=800, height=1000, left=10, top=25');
                    newWin.document.write('<table>' + document.getElementsByName(tableName).innerHTML + '</table>');
                    newWin.document.close();
                    newWin.focus();
                    newWin.print();
                    newWin.close();
                    return false;
                }
```

Hope this helps!!!